# How does JTAG program an MCU

Tags: flash, jtag

How would JTAG program an MCU with flash memory? I realise that this probably varies from chip to chip, but I'm assuming there's some process they all have in common. Specifically, I'm asking in regards to the LPC1768, which doesn't specify how you would do this is the datasheet.

Comment: Look at the ARM JTAG documents, eg.  ADIv5.2

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, Thanks. Struggling to understand it. Could you refer me to the pages which explain flash programming?

Comment: Not only should you look at JTAG documents that Sphero has explained but I'd also into what module you wish to utilize for JTAG like Keil or Black Magic Probe, etc. This is a vague question because you're asking an idea of JTAG rather than choosing something in particular.

Comment: Are you trying to understand the JTAG protocol or how a chip implements it?

Comment: @whatsisname, I'm trying to understand the process used to program flash memory on an LPC1768 via JTAG.

Answer (score 9):

> How would JTAG program an MCU with flash memory?

In most MCUs, JTAG is not directly connected to flash. There is actually a stack of access methods, each with their protocol. A debugger / in-system programmer has to "talk" to all of them to actually reach the Flash.

> Specifically, I'm asking in regards to the LPC1768

LPCs are ARM Cortex-M based. They use the [debug infrastructure from ARM](https://static.docs.arm.com/ihi0031/c/IHI0031C_debug_interface_as.pdf). The path from JTAG to Flash is:

JTAG -> JTAG-DP -> AHB-AP -> Main AHB bus -> Flash

But we will not actually take this direct path. LPCs expose flashing function through IAP.

Let's detail the steps:

### JTAG

JTAG is the usual name for a wire protocol that exposes a chain of TAPs (Test Access Ports) through 4 wires (TCK TMS TDI TDO). A JTAG Chain is a big chain of shift registers, with a standardized method for selecting register of each TAP, and accessing register value. TAPs can expose an arbitrary set of registers of arbitrary size.

JTAG-DP (JTAG Debug Port) is a TAP specified by ARM, it mainly uses two 32-bit registers called DPACC and APACC (35 bits actually, because of concatenation with 3 operation bits), allowing access to AP and DP. This is entry point for ARM debug model.

### ARM Debug port and Access port

ARM's Debug Port is a gateway to Access Ports. Access ports expose interface to something else. DP can multiplex accesses to 256 APs. Most MCUs in LPCs range contain only one AP, which gives access to internal AHB (Amba Host Bridge) i.e. the internal switching matrix that interconnects the CPU and all other IPs. (Well, actually, AHB-AP is not directly connected to main bus, but goes to a debug bus tightly coupled to CPU, see Cortex design documents for gory details).

ARM's design for Cortex-M debug is memory-based: debugger interface gives access to memory (address+data, read/write, etc.), and CPU debug management (halting, inspecting registers, etc.) is done through memory-mapped registers accessible through the memory interface (See Chap 10 in [Cortex-M3 TRM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0337e/DDI0337E_cortex_m3_r1p1_trm.pdf)).

### Main bus

When we get there, we have access to main memory bus and we can control CPU. Through memory bus, we have access to all internal IPs as if we were running code from CPU.

### Chip-specific init

Today, most MCUs involve proper power management. This generally involves two main aspects: power gating (taking off power from parts of the chip) and clock management (oscillator enabling and clock routing).

Most chips do not magically enable power gates and clocks when a debugger is plugged in, so debugger also has to do platform management and perform proper initialization of various MCU IPs before actually reaching the internal Flash.

### Flash

So, are we able to talk to Flash IP then ?

Yes, but not efficiently.

If we do all the memory accesses from the external debugger by the book, this will work, but will be extremely slow. The problem we have with JTAG access is it generally involves going through an USB-based probe with a big (~milliseconds) round-trip time. Flash IP accesses usually involve an algorithm like:

1. Enable write access
2. Write destination address
3. Write one data word
4. Wait for IP to be ready by polling
5. Trigger write operation
6. Wait for IP to be ready by polling
7. Go back to 2, ad libitum

There is too much polling, if we loose a few milliseconds for every iteration of this loop, our few tens of KiB of code will take ages to program. We'll try to eliminate this.

### Efficient Flash access

General case is to upload a little program in RAM of MCU able to copy chunks of data from RAM to Flash. Idea is to avoid USB round trips by making big unconditional uploads of data from debugger to RAM (they can be batched in one USB transaction), and let the CPU do the copy to flash (which is generally done word-by-word).

Some manufacturers (either because they want to [hide implementations details of their flash IP](http://dmitry.gr/?r=05.Projects&proj=24.%20PSoC4%20confidential), or because they want to ease their customer's lives) implement a set of ROM-based routines you can call directly from debugger port to do different kind of tasks, including chip identification, programming, erasing. NXP implements such kind of ROM in the LPC lineup, they call it IAP.

### Variations around this pattern

JTAG alternatives exist. ARM has such an option called SWD. SWD exposes the same DP (debug port) and AP (Access port) register model. There exist SWD/JTAG variants (called SWJ-DP) that can dynamically switch from JTAG to SWD and vice-versa.

ARM DP/AP model alternatives exist. Former ARMs have a different model, and every other CPU vendor has its own way of bridging the JTAG (or other debug wire protocol) to internals.

Bridging debug access port to memory is an option, but other vendors make the debug port access CPU registers directly. Then debugger may access memory either by injecting actual CPU instructions in the CPU (like loads and stores), or have special pseudo-registers that trigger memory accesses. Ti CC2xxx and Mips are examples of such architectures.

Some vendors also chose to have a direct path from Debug port to Flash IP, but this is quite uncommon for today's MCUs where we have a debug capability anyway (because it gives indirect access to flash). This used to be common for parts where the internal CPU had no write access to internal flash.

Comment: +1 At least some of Microchip's ARM M7 variants define JTAG pins, but they are only for boundary scan. "The JTAG Debug Port TDI, TDO, TMS and TCK is inactive. It is provided for Boundary Scan Manufacturing Test purpose only."

Comment: What do you mean by IP, for example, Flash IP?

Comment: @B4039 Yes, indeed. In SoC industry, all internal components are referred as IP. Flash is one of them.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm asking in regards to the LPC1768, which doesn't specify how you would do this is the datasheet.

Actually, it does in the reference manual (UM10360.pdf). You just put data into the RAM and execute the IAP `CopyRamToFlash()` function. Yes, even when using a debugger.

The debug interface itself is documented by the Core IP provider (ARM) at http://infocenter.arm.com (but may require registration for the full document).

There is support in the open souce OpenOCD project - one could look into the souce code here.

Comment: Surely this requires some kind of bootloader to already be on the MCU, otherwise it wouldn't be in-application-proramming.

Comment: This MCU hast its ISP and IAP functions already in (mask-) ROM.  See mentioned UM10360.pdf manual chapter 32.8.

Comment: Which memory address would you start flashing to when downloading a program?

Comment: I used OpenOCD to flash and debug my LPC1768.

Comment: Does it choose the starting address automatically then? I'm also planning to use OpenOCD to flash my LPC1768. Would you happen to have instructions for this?

Answer (score 2):

Being cortex-m3 based JTAG isnt necessarily the right term, SWD would be more like it.

It varies from chip to chip, design to design.  This is a very broad question.

A shorter answer, and perhaps in line with something that is sometimes in common.  If a chip offers in application programming meaning a program running on that processor can erase/write the flash that that processor uses and hopefully the flash block it boots from, then using an on chip debugger which the cortex-m3 has, you can reach in through an interface SWD/JTAG, whatever they offer, to talk to that debugger.  You tell that on chip debugger, although this is processor and debugger specific, to stop the processor.  In this case the on chip debugger has full access to the amba/axi/apb/etc bus(es) on the edge of the cortex-m3, so anything you can do from a program on the cortex-m3 that generates bus transactions you can do through the debugger through the processor bus into the vendor area of the chip including talking to the flash peripheral.  This is one not uncommon way to do this.

Some mcus have a specific logic interface for the purpose of in curcuit programming that does not necessarily (probably doesnt) go through the processor core, but bypasses to the flash itself or some fraction of the peripheral.  Look at the ISP interface for the AVR (there is more than one different AVR interface BTW the xmegas vs the non-xmegas), these are probably logic based and not a bootloader, and not JTAG.

Not uncommon to have a factory burned bootloader in the chip, like the NXP chips typically, like the one you have, the ST cortex-ms as well, Atmel ARM7 but doesnt look like the cortex-ms, and so on.  Sometimes you can replace the factory installed bootloader, sometimes not.  These can use any interface they design in, sometimes uart, based, spi, i2c, usb, custom.

And then there is pure JTAG which I wonder if these chips have at all since a lot of mcus dont have a lot of pins and few/none to spare.  JTAG is an access method if you will when talking about JTAG debuggers, JTAG is the way you get to the debugger, its not JTAG that is the key it is that there is a debugger that has an interface and it happens to be connected to a JTAG interface, kind of like saying I have a debugger that I connected to a SPI dependent interface.  Its just the access method.  JTAG in general is used for a number of other things and was meant for something other than on chip debugging, and is still very much used for non-on chip debugging.  So it is technically possible that a JTAG chain could be connected to a flash interface, they often connect to SRAM for on wafer and/or after packaging testing of the SRAM (or starting and checking mbist) so they might have access to a flash as well if the design is such, and with that you could with the right scan chains manipulate the flash interface in a way to program it.  If there was a good use case to need to program that flash in circuit, they would put something simpler in there which is what they do for MCUs.

Each processor design may or may not have an on chip debugger and the design of that debugger is whatever they chose, no reason to assume that any two vendors processors designs are remotely the same.  The FUNCTIONALITY is often the same you can often go through the on chip debugger to access the processors bus to then access the rest of the chip, its just the communication path and protocol and features that differ.  Some processors may not have an on chip debugger, one could imagine a design where a chip developer has placed something on the processors main bus that allows access to override and take over that bus as a backdoor around the processor.

The ARM cortex-m debug interface is documented at ARM.  The chip vendor information is documented by the chip vendor, often you can somewhat front door your way in through the processors bus to the peripherals so back/side door accesses that take over a peripheral not through the processors busses are often not needed, but if present then one would hope the chip vendor documents that in the form of the external interface/protocol needed for that access, how the internals actually work is their IP and no reason they have to share.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm assuming there's some process they all have in common.

Broadly speaking, there are three common patterns for programming flash over JTAG:

1. Write data directly into the flash control registers to command it to program flash memory. This is often slow, but has minimal requirements on the microcontroller.
2. Write a small temporary program into RAM (or use code already present in ROM) which will copy data placed in RAM into flash.
3. Use microcontroller-specific JTAG operations to write directly to flash.

Of these three patterns, the second one is the most common. And, as explained in Turbo J's answer, this is the one which the LPC1768 uses.

Comment: Ahhhh, perhaps that explains why the OpenOCD code for the LPC1768 includes several IAP routines. So, is it essentially writing a temporary program to RAM which then uses IAP to program flash?

You say Option 2 is what the LPC1768 uses, but shouldn't it also be possible to write directly to flash using JTAG, without the use of the temporary program?

Comment: @B4039 It's possible in theory, but the documentation for the LPC1768 doesn't cover the hardware interface to flash memory. The routines in ROM (which are used as part of the bootloader) appear to be the _only_ documented interface for writing to flash.

Answer (score -3):

Each "JTAG" interface uses model-specific access control targeted at specific device. Making a JTAG debugger from raw specifications is beyond capabilities of a DIY user, and might employ some security methods that require some licensing.

Per your other questions, you purchased the board from no-name manufacturer on a fishy Internet site. As such, the board apparently comes with no documentation nor toolchain support.

Instead you should go for the original manufacturer, [NXP/Freescale/Motorola](https://www.nxp.com/search?keyword=LPC1768), and get [their development kit](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/brochure/LPC1768.pdf), with all necessary tutorials and tools and support, get it [from Mouser](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/NXP-Semiconductors/OM11043598) or alike

Comment: I already have that board, but it doesn't have all the pins out (especially the QEI ones I need). Regardless, that's not why I'm asking. It would of course be simpler to program the board using ISP, but I'm interested in understanding how the JTAG process works.

Comment: @B4039, what do you mean "how"? A chip usually has some dedicated (or shared) pins that turn on TAP (Test Access Port or something), and then the port assumes serial commands and data streams from JTAG controller under specific application software control (which is aware of particularities of that specific processor), and can dump all covered F-Fs into one or more JTAG chains. Although basic JTAG commands are standardized, all bit mapping and access control to them (to flash in particular) are proprietary and device-specific.

Comment: This is pretty much pure *misinformation* of the sort that is commonly termed "Fear, Uncertainty, and Doubt" if it were not, as in this case, spoken from a perspective of pure *ignorance*.  In actual fact, *all* of the necessary information, both to make a JTAG adapter, to use it for communication, and to write to flash memory thereby, is public.  And it *all* has existing open source implementations (for the debug adapter, open source from no less than Arm Holdings!) so even though original development work is fully possible, none is actually needed.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, the Debug Interface Architecture document (https://static.docs.arm.com/ihi0031/d/debug_interface_v5_2_architecture_specification_IHI0031D.pdf) seems to suggest that programming the flash can be done by first toggling DBGTMS to Shift-IR, selecting the AP register, and then selecting DRW and TAR registers to shift data into the required addresses. Is this correct?

Comment: Probably something like that for the communication with a lot more steps to use it to actually write to flash.  But between open source CMSIS-DAP (or blackmagic, or just using an FT2232) and open source OpenOCD to drive it, you don't actually need to concern yourself with implementation detail unless it's something you find interesting to dig into or you're using a cutting edge chip requiring minor modifications - in those cases, the code being open source, you're fully free to.

Comment: I'm not planning on implementing it, just like to know what's happening "under the hood" of implementations such as OpenOCD.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, although with OpenOCD, isn't it required to define this "process" when configuring it for use with certain chips, all of which have different programming processes?

Comment: Well, TurboJ gave you a sense of that - JTAG extensions for raw communication with the ARM debug engine, then go through something often involving loading up the data into RAM, then invoking some delegate code in RAM or even jumping into a vendor ROM to do the actual writes.

Comment: @B4039 - someone had to make OpenOCD config files and write some flash algorithm specific C code, but that's probably already there for your not-exactly-new target processor.  Have you looked?

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I was only able to find an LPC1768 config file, no C code.

Comment: The algorithms are typically shared across families of similar chips. 
 For the LPC1768 I'd suspect it's probably in src/flash/nor/lpc2000.c but my version is a bit old and it may have moved.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I've had a look. It seems to make many calls to IAP functions. Why is this so? Isn't IAP for existing programs to modify/erase/write flash memory, hence the name? If there is nothing written on the flash, then why make calls to IAP functions?

Comment: @B4039 because leveraging the existing flashing code is the easiest way to do it.  It may also be the *only* way that works - flash has timing considerations.